# How to I make my column number dynamic with css display grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently using css `display: grid;` and `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;` to display the layout as shown in the image. My question is how to I make my column dynamic. At the moment, I hard-coded it by putting 10 `auto` which is referring to 10 columns but my table column is dynamic. Some have 8 columns. I already have my dynamic column number calculated in my Javascript / Jquery. I don't have anything like sass. Do I need it to get this done?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Comment: thanks. it works. solved it with `document.getElementById("seatAvailable").style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${hallCol},auto)`;`

Answer (score 0):

1) Changing the number of columns by JavaScript

```
const cols = 10;
object.style.gridTemplateColumns=`repeat(${cols},auto)`;
```

2) Changing the number of columns in PHP

```
<?php $cols = 10; ?>
...
<div class="grid" style="--cols: <?php echo $cols; ?>;">...</div>
```

and the following CSS code

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
}
```